# Add progress bar to HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar, css-animations

I Want to add a column of progress bar to each row of html table to show processing of each file.

I want to have with animation like first file goes from 0% to 100% then row 2 or second file starts processing from 0% to 100% and so on.

Just I want 1 button to start animation after completing 1st then it should start next and so on.
Code for table and progress bar is below ? can anybody help me to integrate both of them.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  #myProgress {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ddd;
  }
  
  #myBar {
    width: 1%;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

  <div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar"></div>
  </div>

  <br>
  <button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>

  <script>
    function move() {
      var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
      var width = 1;
      var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

      function frame() {
        if (width >= 100) {
          clearInterval(id);
        } else {
          width++;
          elem.style.width = width + '%';
        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems like the above is for the progress bar only. Do you intend to add the code for your table as well?

Comment: i was trying but not able to upload due to technical issues... In case you can try using code for html table using this :-https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_intro

Comment: Ok I see the table, I see the progress bar. What do you mean by `integrating` here?

Comment: i want to add column in table which shows progress of each row in table ....just like the way we show processing of files in que mechanism .....i hope i am clear ?

Comment: do u just want to have progress bar(without animation) to indicate status ? or u want to have progress bar with the animation.@Paras Ghai

Comment: I want to have with animation....like first file goes from 0% to 100% ....then row 2 or second file starts processing from 0% to 100% and so on.....

Comment: I am having solution for  your question using  css @keyframes  shall i upload it ?@Paras Ghai

Comment: @amaresh yeah please ...i am stuck with this from lomg time now....any help will be great

Comment: do u want to have a button and start animation after clicking or do u want start animation when page is loaded ? @ParasGhai

Comment: No...i want a button to start animation

Comment: You seem to have several questions here. I would say you should try to work on this. I do not see much effort in the code posted above.

Comment: Yeahh..it almost solved the problem ......incase you can edit it a way that progress bar start one by one instead of all at one go...it will be great..... Thankyou so much :)

Comment: do u want to have separate button for each one? or just one btn and start animate it one by one @ParasGhai

Comment: just one button to start aninate one by one...

Comment: Yes ...it solved my problem..Thankyou so much for help ..much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A column of progress bar on each row of html table to show processing of each file.

```js
function start_animation(){ 
 setTimeout( 
function animation1() {
document.getElementsByClassName("one")[0].style.animation = "one 2s linear forwards";
setTimeout(animation1, 100);}, 100 ); 
 next1(); }
function next1(){
  setTimeout( 
function animation2() {
document.getElementsByClassName("one")[1].style.animation = "one 2s linear forwards";
setTimeout(animation2, 100);}, 2600);  
 next2();}
function next2(){
  setTimeout( 
function animation3() {
document.getElementsByClassName("one")[2].style.animation = "one 2s linear forwards";
setTimeout(animation3, 100);}, 4550);
next3();}
function next3(){
  setTimeout( 
function animation4() {
document.getElementsByClassName("two")[0].style.animation = "two 2s linear forwards";
setTimeout(animation4, 100);},6400);}
```

```css
 body {
  font-family: Open Sans, San-Serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #595959;
  margin: 20px;
}
 th {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  padding: 5px 0;
}
 td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 34px;
     text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid 1px  #ccc;
}

.one{
line-height: 25px;
 border-radius:5px;
 text-align:center;
display: block;
 color:white;
height:25px;
}
@keyframes one{                
0%{
width:0%;
}
100%{
width:100%;
background-color:#5dc96e;
}
}
.two{
text-align:center;
line-height:25px;
height: 25px;
 border-radius:5px;
display: block;
 color:white;
}

@keyframes two{                
0%{
width:0%;
}
100%{
width:40%;
background-color:red;
}
}
```

```html
<input value="Start Animation" name="" type="button" onclick="start_animation()" />
<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Files</th> 
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>1.2MB</th>
    <th>Status </th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>File 1</td>
    <td>Excel</td>
    <td>2MB</td>
    <td >
<span class="one">100%</span>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>File 2</td>
    <td>word</td>
    <td>100Kb</td>
    <td >
<span class="one">100%</span>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>File 3</td>
    <td>Word</td>
    <td>800Kb</td>
    <td >
   <span class="one">100%</span>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>File 4 </td>
    <td>Power Point</td>
    <td>1MB</td>
    <td>
<span class="two">40%</span>       
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Progress status shown one by one on the right of each row.

In Addition, Whenever you click on the button (Activate Progress bar).  it changes to Deactivate Progress bar and the progress will be shown one by one on the right of each row.

On further click it changes to Activate Progress bar and the progress will go to the starting stage(0%).

and vice versa..

```js
var btm = document.getElementById("m");
  
btm.onclick = function() {

if (btm.innerHTML == "Activate Progress bar") {
    btm.innerHTML = "Deactivate Progress bar";
  } else {
    btm.innerHTML = "Activate Progress bar";
  }

var x = document.getElementById("myBar");

if(x.style.width == '100%') {
      x.style.width='0%';
      x.style.transition='1s';
      }
else {
 x.style.width='100%';
    x.style.transition='1s';
}

var x = document.getElementById("myBar2");

if(x.style.width == '60%') {
      x.style.width='0%';
      x.style.transition='1s';
      x.style.transitionDelay='.5s';
      }
else {
 x.style.width='60%';
    x.style.transition='1s';
    x.style.transitionDelay='.5s';
    
}

var x = document.getElementById("myBar3");

if(x.style.width == '30%') {
      x.style.width='0%';
      x.style.transition='1s';
      x.style.transitionDelay='1s';
      }
else {
 x.style.width='30%';
    x.style.transition='1s';
    x.style.transitionDelay='1s';

}

}
```

```css
#myProgress #myProgress2 #myProgress3{
    width: 100%;
}
#myBar {
    width:0%;
    line-height: 30px;
    color:white;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}
#myBar2 {
    width:0%;
    line-height: 30px;
    color:white;
    background-color: #79cedc;
}
#myBar3 {
    width:0%;
    line-height: 30px;
    color:white;
    background-color: #ec3047;
}
table {
   height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
table td {
   width:50%;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
table th {
    background:black;
    color:white;
    padding:5px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
table td:nth-child(odd) {
    border:1px solid black;
    color:black;
}
button {
    padding:5px;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    background:white;
    color:blue;
    border:1px solid black;
}
button:focus {
    outline:none;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Status</th>

    <tr>
      <td>progress 1</td>
      <td>
          <div id="myProgress">
            <div id="myBar">(100%)</div>
          </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>progress 2</td>
      <td>
        <div id="myProgress2">
          <div id="myBar2">(60%)</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>progress 3</td>
      <td>
        <div id="myProgress3">
          <div id="myBar3">(30%)</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button id='m'>Activate Progress bar</button>
```